# How would you process sparql xml directly when QueryWithResultSet doesn't work

Tags: c#, dotnetrdf

Over the past year or so, I've been using a bunch of custom code to handle interaction with a number of `SPARQL` endpoints.  I'd rather not have to maintain it, so I've been learning how to use `dotnetrdf`.  The problem I have, is I'm running into endpoints that I can't get to work.  Here's an example:
Endpoint: `http://id.ndl.go.jp/auth/ndla
SPARQL Query`:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX xl: <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#>
SELECT ?subj WHERE { 
{?subj rdfs:label ?heading} UNION
{?subj xl:altLabel [ xl:literalForm ?heading]}
filter (?heading = "軍事基地.")
}
```

If you run this query as a `GET` Request, it works: [`SPARQL QUERY`](http://id.ndl.go.jp/auth/ndla?query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20<http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23>%20%0APREFIX%20xl%3A%20<http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2008%2F05%2Fskos-xl%23>%0ASELECT%20%3Fsubj%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%7B%3Fsubj%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fheading%7D%20UNION%0A%20%7B%3Fsubj%20xl%3AaltLabel%20%5B%20xl%3AliteralForm%20%3Fheading%5D%7D%0A%20filter%20(%3Fheading%20%3D%20"%E8%BB%8D%E4%BA%8B%E5%9F%BA%E5%9C%B0")%0A%20%7D)

The problem I'm having with `dotnetref` is when I try the following:

```
SparqlRemoteEndpoint endpoint = new SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new Uri(@"http://id.ndl.go.jp/auth/ndla"));
endpoint.HttpMode = "GET";               
SparqlResultSet results = endpoint.QueryWithResultSet(textBox1.Text);
```

The request is always passed as a `POST` request -- even though I've specified otherwise, and I always get back the `HTML` results page.  If I try to access the page directly, I get the data:

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://id.ndl.go.jp/auth/ndla?query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0APREFIX%20xl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2008%2F05%2Fskos-xl%23%3E%0ASELECT%20%3Fsubj%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%7B%3Fsubj%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fheading%7D%20UNION%0A%20%7B%3Fsubj%20xl%3AaltLabel%20%5B%20xl%3AliteralForm%20%3Fheading%5D%7D%0A%20filter%20(%3Fheading%20%3D%20%22%E8%BB%8D%E4%BA%8B%E5%9F%BA%E5%9C%B0%22)%0A%20%7D");

System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();           
System.IO.Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(s);
string _s = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
s.Close();
```

This gets me the raw `sparql xml`, and I can do stuff with it, but I still want to take advantage of `dotnetrdf`'s parsers.  So, I guess I have two questions.

1. I can't figure out why the above endpoint doesn't work.  Using the
   FullHTTPDebugging`is how I can see that the`HTTPMode` isn't doing
   anything -- all data is being sent as a post.  Is there a way to
   force the Method (I'm using the 2.0 prerelease 8 for this particular
   test)
2. Assuming I can't make this endpoint work, is there a way to feed the
   `SPARQL xml` response retrieved via the `HttpWebResponse` method
   back into the the library to create a `SparqlResultSet`.

I think either of the above would solve my problem as I could assume if the initial query failed, I should fall back to a direct request, and then push the `sparql xml` back into the library to generate the `resultset`.

Comment: I did some additional experimentation and it appears that the presence of Unicode characters causes the sparql remote request to only post.  This doesn't seem like expected functionality, so I filed an issue here: https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/issues/128